# How to separate activities

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, zxing

I have several `onActivityResult` activities in my Android app and I am having an issue with two activities running at one time. When I open up my ZXing barcode scanner it will close the connection to my Bluetooth printer. Here is my code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String address = data.getExtras()
                            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                    con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);

                    mService.connect(con_dev);
                }
                break;
        }
            IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (scanningResult != null) {
                String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                edtContext.setText(scanContent);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
    }
```

What would be the best way to split up these activities so that they do not overlap each other?

UPDATE:
As @Mahfa stated I need to add a requestCode to the scanning activity. This is my code for the button that starts the scanning activity:

```
btnBarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);
        OnClickListener BarcodeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBarcode) {
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(PrintDemo.this);
                    integrator.initiateScan();
                }
            }
        };
        btnBarcode.setOnClickListener(BarcodeOnClickListener);
```

What do I need to do to add a requestCode to this?

Comment: you can't separate results with requestCode ?

Comment: That's what I was thinking I would need to do, but I am not sure how to implement it. I have updated the question.

Comment: take a look at here i hadn't used zxing before but there is gotta be a way to set requestCode . http://stackoverflow.com/a/25630424/2690277 . https://www.google.com/search?q=set+requestCode+in+zxing&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=set+intent+requestCode+in+zxing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mahfa put me on the right track with the links that he posted and eventually I found this code example that cleared up my issue http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=jdkernel-updater-master/src/jdkernel/ui/ThemeListNewActivity.java

Here is my completed code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String address = data.getExtras()
                            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                    con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);

                    mService.connect(con_dev);
                }
                break;
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
                IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (scanningResult != null) {
                    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                    String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                    //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                    edtContext.setText(scanContent);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                break;
        }
```

I did not have to change anything on my `OnClickListener`. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Mahfa.